# Infinite divisibility of random variables

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, statistics, random-variables

A random variable $X$ is infinitely divisible if for any positive integer $k$, there exist $k$ i.i.d. random variables $Y_1,...,Y_k$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^k Y_i = X$. Given the PDF of an arbitrary unbounded random variable, how can we determine if it is infinitely divisible? Assuming the random variable $X$ is in fact infinitely divisible, is there an algorithm to determine the distribution of $Y_i$?

Comment: To get the PDF of $Y_i$, you could use the transform domain (where convolution becomes multiplication).  For intuition, you could see how Poissons or Gaussians behave in the transform domain.

Comment: Also, google "Levy-Khintchine"

Comment: Dumb question: Does the text of wherever you learned the term 'infinitely divisible' give you the answer? Perhaps somewhere in the footnotes, appendix or bibliography, it tells you where you might read more about those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be extremely difficult to say whether a given distribution is infinitely divisible or not. Infinitely divisible distribution are studied using characteristic functions. If you know that $X$ is Infinitely divisible then the characteristic function of $Y_i$ is the n-th root of the characteristic function of $X$ but you have to define the n-th root carefully. The distribution of $Y_i$ can be written down explicitly only in very few cases.